# Is $g(f(x))$ always greater than $f(g(x))$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

This question might be trivial or might not have a general answer, but maybe someone can help me:

If we have two functions: $f,g: \mathbb{R}^+ \to \mathbb{R}^+ $ with $g^\prime(x)> f^\prime(x)>0, \space \forall x \in \mathbb{R}^+$ 

will $\space g(f(x))$ be greater than $f(g(x))$ $\space$for all $x$?

Edit: I should rather ask if $\space g(f(x)) \geq f(g(x))$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $f(x)=x^2$ and $g(x)=x^2+x$, then $g'(x)=2x+1>f'(x)=2x>0$, but

$$g(f(x))=x^4+x^2<f(g(x))=(x^2+x)^2=(x^4+x^2)+2x^3.$$

Comment: It appears to me that $g'(x) = 1/2$, and $f'(x) = 1$...

Comment: Oops, my bad... I have fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is true. Consider the counterexample:

$$
f(x) = x \\
g(x) = 2x
$$

We have that $g^{'}(x) = 2 > f^{'}(x) = 1>0$. Also,

$$
f(g(x)) = 2x\\
g(f(x)) = 2x
$$

Hence we have equality, which disproves the statement.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. But is $g(f(x)) \geq f(g(x))$ ?

Comment: Yes, silly mistake on my part. Thanks @André

Comment: @juliangst consider $f(x) = x - 5$ and $g(x) = 2x$, $f(g(x)) = 2x - 5$ and $g(f(x)) = 2x - 10$

Comment: Thanks, that definietly answers the question. I came across the questions when I watched the numberphile video about $TREE(g_{64})$ and $g(TREE(3))$, so I wondered if there is a general statement that includes two really fast growing functions with one growing even faster than the other one.

Comment: @LearningMathematics But $f(1)=-4$ is negative..